# Can someone help me out with this mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')'

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO 
                    topics(topic_subject,
                           topic_date,
                           topic_cat,
                           topic_by)
               VALUES('" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['topic_subject']) . "',
                           NOW(),
                           " . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['topic_cat']) . ",
                           " . $_SESSION['fullname'] . "
                           )";
```

Comment: You're missing quotes around the name

Comment: And that's one of those problems that wouldn't arise with a newer database interface. Parameter binding is much simpler than patching together a SQL query.

Comment: @john conde added the quotes but still the problem persists..

Comment: @mario at this point cant go with the newer interface this is the only problem i am facing rightnow rest all is working fine..

Answer (score 1):

You are missing quotes around string values here is your new sql

```
ql = "INSERT INTO 
                        topics(topic_subject,
                               topic_date,
                               topic_cat,
                               topic_by)
                   VALUES('" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['topic_subject']) . "',
                               NOW(),
                               '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['topic_cat']) . "',
                               '" . $_SESSION['fullname'] . "'
                               )";
```

Comment: you may be correct but this din't solve my problem yet..

Comment: what is the error that you have

Comment: it is same as before You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 11

Comment: Try to put  space between topics and (

Comment: that is not going to help but i'll give it a try..

Comment: nope....still the same..

Comment: i am feeling like the problem is somewhere else only,....

Comment: Can you echo $sql after running your code?

Comment: INSERT INTO topics(topic_subject, topic_date, topic_cat, topic_by) VALUES ('afe e', NOW(), '5', '' )An error occured while inserting your post. Please try again later.

Comment: topic_by is not getting stored..

Comment: wokay i'll check that out..

Answer (score 1):

You need to put quotes around the value that are stored as VARCHAR, I guess `$_SESSION['fullname']` in this case. Like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO 
                    topics(topic_subject,
                           topic_date,
                           topic_cat,
                           topic_by)
               VALUES('" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['topic_subject']) . "',
                           NOW(),
                           " . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['topic_cat']) . ",
                           '" . $_SESSION['fullname'] . "'
                           )";
```

Comment: you may be correct but this din't solve my problem yet..

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

You were missing single quotations.

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO 
                topics(topic_subject,
                       topic_date,
                       topic_cat,
                       topic_by)
           VALUES('" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['topic_subject']) . "',
                       NOW(),
                       '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['topic_cat']) . "',
                       '" . $_SESSION['fullname'] . "'
                       )";
```

Comment: you may be correct but this din't solve my problem yet..